# Get entries of a file from a filtered list

Tags: powershell

I am trying to grab the host file entries of servers in mulptiple OUs here to show the host file entries and server names

```
$OUpath = 

     'OU=Sales,OU=Servers,OU=_Production,OU=Upgraded,DC=fabrikam,DC=local'
     'OU=DCHR,OU=Servers,OU=_Production,OU=Upgraded,DC=fabrikam,DC=local'
      'OU=Finance,OU=Servers,OU=Test,OU=Upgraded,DC=fabrikam,DC=local'
 

$ExportPath = 'c:\servers.csv'
$OUpath | Foreach {
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase $OUpath} | Select-object DistinguishedName,DNSHostName,Name,Description | Export-Csv -NoType $ExportPath
```

Part A up ran fine...How can i get the entries of the results. I am tending towards content but hope to have it all in one script. Any help would be nice.

Comment: You have confused `ForEach` with `ForEach-Object` and you are passing in a single string to the for each regardless making it irrelevant. Since it is irrelevant it is also unnecessary for the task at hand as you can just use `ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase $OUpath`.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to [@FoxDeploy's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67941823/15339544) helpful answer, here is how you can do the same using the pipelines with `ForEach-Object`.

**Note that `Description` is not a default property for `Get-ADComputer` you will need to add `-Properties Description` to see it's value.**

Another point to consider, by default, if you don't specify **the `-SearchScope`, `Get-ADComputer` will perform a `SubTree` search**, meaning that it will bring all computers of the specified OU and **all** computers on all the OUs contained in the **Base OU**. If you just want to bring the computers in the OU without going down in recursion, you should add **`-SearchScope OneLevel`**.

```
@(
    'OU=Sales,OU=Servers,OU=_Production,OU=Upgraded,DC=fabrikam,DC=local'
    'OU=DCHR,OU=Servers,OU=_Production,OU=Upgraded,DC=fabrikam,DC=local'
    'OU=Finance,OU=Servers,OU=Test,OU=Upgraded,DC=fabrikam,DC=local'
) | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase $_ -Properties Description
} | Select-Object DistinguishedName,DNSHostName,Name,Description |
Export-Csv 'c:\servers.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1):

With some minor restructuring, this should get you past your issue

```
$OUpath = (
     'OU=Sales,OU=Servers,OU=_Production,OU=Upgraded,DC=fabrikam,DC=local',
     'OU=DCHR,OU=Servers,OU=_Production,OU=Upgraded,DC=fabrikam,DC=local',
      'OU=Finance,OU=Servers,OU=Test,OU=Upgraded,DC=fabrikam,DC=local')
 

$ExportPath = 'c:\servers.csv'
$servers = new-object System.Collections.ArrayList
ForEach($path in $OUpath){
    $ouServers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase $path | Select-object DistinguishedName,DNSHostName,Name,Description
    $servers.AddRange($ouServers) | Out-Null
}

"found $($servers.Count) servers!"
$servers | export-csv $exportPath
```

I made the list of OU Paths a PowerShell array, then iterate through them using the standalone `ForEach` loop.  Then commit the items to a variable that will persist (`$servers`) and output the CSV.

Comment: Thanks. I will give this a try. I don't care for the description properties really so yeah thanks. The results of the search base looks fine but am also trying to grab the host file entries in them. I know some of them need are offline and some might need their path tested if upgraded.

Answer (score 1):

I think the primary issues were the array getting declared incorrectly, and incorrect syntax for the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet

```
$OUpath = @(
    'OU=Sales,OU=Servers,OU=_Production,OU=Upgraded,DC=fabrikam,DC=local'
    'OU=DCHR,OU=Servers,OU=_Production,OU=Upgraded,DC=fabrikam,DC=local'
    'OU=Finance,OU=Servers,OU=Test,OU=Upgraded,DC=fabrikam,DC=local'
)

$ExportPath = 'c:\servers.csv'

$OUpath | 
ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase $_ -Properties Description
} | 
Select-Object DistinguishedName, DNSHostName, Name, Description | 
Export-Csv $ExportPath -NoTypeInformation
```

You have to use `$_` in this context where you were using `$OUpath` previously.    `Select-Object` can take the the piped output from the `ForEach-Object` loop rather than being in the loop, which should be more efficient.  Likewise for `Export-Csv`.

As implied by [FoxDeply's very good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67941823/4749264) that might signal an attempt to use A `ForEach(...)` loop construct instead of `ForEach-Object`. But if we are going that route I think it's slightly better to let PowerShell populate the array for us.

```
$OUpath = @(
    'OU=Sales,OU=Servers,OU=_Production,OU=Upgraded,DC=fabrikam,DC=local'
    'OU=DCHR,OU=Servers,OU=_Production,OU=Upgraded,DC=fabrikam,DC=local'
    'OU=Finance,OU=Servers,OU=Test,OU=Upgraded,DC=fabrikam,DC=local'
)
 
$Servers =
ForEach( $Path in $OUpath )
{
    Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase $path -Properties Description |
    Select-Object DistinguishedName, DNSHostName, Name, Description
}

$Servers | Export-Csv $ExportPath -NoTypeInformation
```

Alternatively you could skip the `Select-Object` inside the loop and add `$Servers = $Servers | Select-Object ...` right after the loop. Although the difference is probably negligible.

Comment: Good to see you around again :)